# Skip multiple lines in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I want to print out only a certain line from the output of a command.
Lets take the example of `ipconfig` command. This returns a lot of lines.

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ab80::456d:123e:5ae5:9ab6%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.33
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I want to just print say the 11th line.

I tried the following

```
FOR /F "skip=10 delims=" %G IN ('IPCONFIG') DO @ECHO %G
```

This skips only the first 10 lines and prints the rest of the lines.

```
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

How do I print **only** the 11th line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just leave the loop

```
FOR /F "skip=10 delims=" %G IN ('IPCONFIG') DO @ECHO %G & goto done
:done
```

**edited** Get the 11th line in the output of a command from a single command line

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig^|findstr /n "^"^|findstr /l /b /c:"11:"') do echo %b
```

Execute the command, number the output, retrieve the required line, split the initial number and echo the rest

```
set "x=1" & for /f "skip=10 delims=" %a in ('ipconfig') do @(if defined x (set "x=" & echo %a))
```

Set a flag variable, execute the command, skip the first 10 lines and for each line if the flag is set, clean the flag and echo the line

Comment: Could I run this in a single command? I mean not through a batch file.

Comment: @ontherocks, i don't see the need, but anyway included.

Answer (score 2):

`Could I run this in a single command? I mean not through a batch file.` yes:

```
ipconfig |find "Default Gateway"
```

(runs both on the command line and in a batch file)

Comment: It should work fine both on the command line, and within a batch script.